# How to move web applications between different machines both running IIS 6.0?

Tags: iis, iis-6, migration

I am trying to move a number of websites / web applications (dozens) scattered over several servers to a new home. Both the source and destination are running IIS 6.0, but are not on the same network (ie different hosting providers and no VPN between the two).

I have had a look at [Internet Information Services 6.0 Migration Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2aefc3e4-ce97-4f25-ace6-127f933a6cd2&displaylang=en) and if that's the best on offer will have to use it, but I was wondering if there were any other solutions available.

Answer (score 1):

The Web Deployment Tool is the new way to do that.  It allows migration of IIS6 to 6, 6 to 7 and 7 to 7.  It allows you to migration other things besides the site configuration.  For example, COM+, registry, content, SSL certs.
http://www.iis.net/extensions/WebDeploymentTool

Answer (score 0):

I have used [IIS Export utility] before with good results. The free version has always worked fine for me. You can export directly to the new server if it is on the same network, or to a database that you can then move to new server and import.